# What can cause a disabled git push button in VSCode?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I cannot push to Github from Visual Studio Code (version 0.5.0). I didn't find any explanation how to set it. It works fine from the console, but I would be happy to know why it doesn't work from VSCode.

What it looks like:

[image: vscode screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a remote configured for your branch?

Comment: @BenjaminPasero is it supposed to be configured separately for VSCode?

Comment: Well you can try to do a "git push" from the command line in that directory and see what git tells you. This might be something else, but lets test that first.

Comment: as i mentioned before, it works fine from the console:  `dev$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.05 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/fullcrimp/rust-guessing-game.git
   df4d903..c456187  master -> master`

Comment: That is interesting. What do you get when you run `git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' refs/heads/master`?

Comment: @JoãoMoreno an empty line

Comment: I have the same problem on GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a working local git, GitHub remote, and command line.

Comment: Yes that is interesting. The upstream link is what VSCode looks at to figure out whether pull, push and sync, which is not always true. Bringing this feedback back to the team.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VSCode looks at whether the branch has an upstream link.

If you want to push/pull your **master** branch to **origin/master**, you can run the following command and set the upstream link:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

From then on VSCode will enable those actions for the master branch.

Comment: Even though my remote to GitHub was already setup I issued the equivalent command, without success, for Git versions < 1.8 specifically in my case v1.7.9.5. I'm on GNU/Linux.  Sync, Push and Pull in VSCode are still disabled. Git works fine from command line though. $ git branch --set-upstream origin/master master